# Is there a way to update existing detectron2's model_final.pth file with new annotations?

Tags: python, detectron

I am  new to machine learning. Need help.
I have been looking for a solution to update the existing detectron2 model_final.pth file with new annotations, can you guys suggest a solution.

As i am new to ML, haven't tried yet, exploring it.

Answer (score 0):

`.pth` file can be updated using `torch`. The code will be like below:

```
import torch
old_model = torch.load("model_final.pth")
new_model = update_annotations(old_model) #update your .pth file here
torch.save(new_model,"model_final.pth")
```